# Replacing words with another word using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. I'm trying to change all instances of hello to hey. I have created a variable text to store the string. I have then tried the replace method on that string, but it does not change the string. I want the text in the `<p>` element tags to be changed to *hey hey hey hey*, but it does not change. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<p id="1">hello hello hello hello</p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var text = document.getElementById("1").textContent;
text = text.replace(/hello/g,"hey");
```

Comment: You just get the text from the element but you never update the content of the element again. It's not enough to just call `replace` on the string

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this .

**Why not working**

1. For that initial call `text= elem.textContent` its read the value.
2. On the second time set `text=replace` value is not possible .Because the text only have string `p` elem not a DOM elem

```js
var text = document.getElementById("1").textContent;
console.log(text) //direct string
text = text.replace(/hello/g, "hey")
```

```html
<p id="1">hello hello hello hello</p>
```

**Solution**

```js
var text = document.getElementById("1");
console.log(text) //dom element 
text.textContent = text.textContent.replace(/hello/g, "hey")
```

```html
<p id="1">hello hello hello hello</p>
```